# Generating separate tabs for individual subsections

Tags: r, r-markdown

I was wondering if I could get some help.

Say I have 3 files:

```
top-level.rmd
q1.rmd
q2.rmd
```

The contents of `top-level.rmd`:

````
---
title: "hw1-2330981"
author: "Ian Quah"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r child = 'q1.Rmd'}

```

```{r child = 'q2.Rmd'}

```
````

(apologies for the formatting coming out weird)

The contents of `q1.rmd`:

````
---
title: "hw_sol_q1"
author: "Ian Quah"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

# Question 1: `pressure.csv` {.tabset}

## a) `getwd()`

```{r }
getwd()
```
````

and the contents for `q2.rmd`

````
---
title: "hw_sol_q1"
author: "Ian Quah"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

# Question 2: something else {.tabset}

## a) `getwd()`

```{r }
getwd()
```
````

---

I am trying to generate two tabs on the main page, where each tab contains a corresponding question with all the sub-questions in a flat format (we scroll down to see the solutions for each subquestion). I've tried adding `{.tabset}` to the top-level header of each question (see below) but the end result isn't what I'm hoping for.

TL;DR I want

---

Top-level page with some text

|tab1| |tab2|

(with tab1 active)

Q1.1

.
.
.

Q1.2

and if I click on tab 2 I will then see

Q2.1

.
.
.

Q2.2

rendered on the top-level

Comment: I suggested an edit that I think better reflects the rmarkdown contents while still allowing embedded code chunks, I hope that met with your intent. Rmd/Qmd docs can be difficult to get right in Stack formatting, the trick is to make your `\`\`\``-fenced code blocks without backslashes and then indent all content 4 (or more) spaces.

Comment: Thank you for making that edit! This was perfect and accomplished exactly what I was hoping for. I'll definitely pay attention to what you changed so that in the future I won't run into this problem again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `.tabset` class on the *mother* element of the tabs:

#### `top-level.Rmd`

````
---
title: "hw1-2330981"
author: "Ian Quah"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Questions {.tabset}

```{r child = 'q1.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'q2.Rmd'}
```
````

#### `q1.Rmd`

````
---
title: "hw_sol_q1"
author: "Ian Quah"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

## Question 1: `pressure.csv`

### a) `getwd()`

```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

#### `q2.Rmd`

````
---
title: "hw_sol_q1"
author: "Ian Quah"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

## Question 2: something else 

### a) `getwd()`

```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

#### Output

[image: Rendered RMarkdown report with two tabs showing the separate questions]

---

#### Additional Remark

If for some reason you do not like to show the (somewhat superfluous) header labeled `Questions`, you can use some custom `CSS` to hide it altogether:

````
```{css, echo = FALSE}
.questions > h1 {
  display: none;
}
```

# Questions {.tabset .questions}
````